# How to access a public ip enabled instance from a another instance where only private ip is available

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

I have two instances in AWS where we have public ip and private ip for one instance and the other instance has only private ip.

Both are in the same VPC and same subnet. However I’m not able to access/ping the public ip from the instance 2. I can ping/access it using private ip. But how can we achieve it using public ip.

I have tried using the icmp rules in the security group but still not accessible.